# creating apple ipad mail view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to create a view that looks like the following:
[image]

I know it's a UISplitView, however my issue is that on creating the UIToolBar that is below the UITableView to the left and also on how to create the icons on top of the detail view (the one with the trash can logo, reply, and new message). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the DetailView.xib for a UISplitView project in Interface Builder you can drag UIBarButtonItems onto the toolbar contained in it.

To get a toolbar in the popover controller you can just use the toobar that comes with a UINavigationController. The code below should give you an idea of how to do this. Add this code to RootViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);

    //setup toolbar
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];    
    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:refreshItem, nil]];
    [refreshItem release];    

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 10.0, 200.0, 21.0)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"This is a label on the toolbar";
    [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}
```

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, what if I wanted to have a toolbar on the DetailView? same with the code above?

Comment: You can just drag a toolbar onto DetaiView in IB.

Comment: well actually my detail view already has a UITableView, so I just need to drag a toolbar in it? Is there a way to do it just programatically

Comment: If your table view is inside of DetailView then you should be able to move the bottom edge of the table view up and add a toolbar to the bottom of detail view.